# Python split string into multiple parts

Tags: python, arrays, string, list, split

I have this string:

```
"[22.190894440000001, -100.99684750999999] 6 2011-08-28 19:48:11 @Karymitaville you can dance you can give having the time of my life(8) ABBA :D"
```

Where

1. the two numbers inside the [] are lat and lang
2. 6 is value
3. 2011-08-28 is the date
4. 19:48:11 is the time
5. rest is the text

I want to separate this string into a list of length 5, in the following format: `[lat, lang, value, date, time, text]`

what is the most efficient way to do so?

Comment: You could use regex to parse the string. https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

Comment: Can you share what you’ve tried / researched on the subject yourself, before posting to SO?  Please update the question accordingly.

Comment: Show what you have tried

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of `str.split` with `maxsplit` argument controlling the number of splits. Then you can `strip` the comma and brackets from `lat` and `lang`:

```
>>> text = "[22.190894440000001, -100.99684750999999] 6 2011-08-28 19:48:11 @Karymitaville you can dance you can give having the time of my life(8) ABBA :D"
>>> lat, lang, value, date, time, text = text.split(maxsplit=5)
>>> lat, lang, value, date, time, text
('[22.190894440000001,', '-100.99684750999999]', '6', '2011-08-28', '19:48:11', '@Karymitaville you can dance you can give having the time of my life(8) ABBA :D')
>>> lat = lat.strip('[').rstrip(',')
>>> lang = lang.rstrip(']')
>>> lat, lang, value, date, time, text
('22.190894440000001', '-100.99684750999999', '6', '2011-08-28', '19:48:11', '@Karymitaville you can dance you can give having the time of my life(8) ABBA :D')
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using regex.

```
import re

text = "[22.190894440000001, -100.99684750999999] 6 2011-08-28 19:48:11 @Karymitaville you can dance you can give having the time of my life(8) ABBA :D"
regex = re.compile(r"\[(?P<lat>\d+.\d+), +(?P<lang>-?\d+.\d+)\] +(?P<value>.+?) *(?P<date>.+?) +(?P<time>.+?) +(?P<text>.*)")

result = regex.match(text)

print(result.group("lat"))
print(result.group("lang"))
print(result.group("value"))
print(result.group("date"))
print(result.group("time"))
print(result.group("text"))
```

The result:

```
22.190894440000001
-100.99684750999999
6
2011-08-28
19:48:11
@Karymitaville you can dance you can give having the time of my life(8) ABBA :D
```